# What is the best way to limit access to a Dashboard with a specific dimension/grouping?

Tags: database-design, data-visualization, tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop

For example, in our data we have a dimension field called 'States' and it has rows of members who live in states all over the US. Let's say we want to do a gradual reveal of a dashboard and only want to limit it to certain states at a time. How would we do this without going into the Tableau groups and permissions and creating new groups there?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a combination between a [data source filter](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_datasource.htm) and [user filters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_userfilters_create.htm).

Create a data source filter to limit the States you want phase in. I'm assuming you only want individuals associated with each state to only see their respective data. That's where a user filter would come in.